# how can i perform 3d Fourier Transform......?

Tags: matlab, fft

i am trying to use `fftn` function but I get errors. My code is:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
% video=VideoReader('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv');
video=read('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\gray\myvideo.avi');
f=fftn(v);
i=imread('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\gray\2.jpg');
f=fftshift(fftn(i));
figure,imshow(i);
figure,imshow(log(1+f),[]);
```

1. When I apply `fftn` for a single frame I get the same results as `fft2` function

   ```
   i=imread('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\gray\2.jpg');
   f=fftshift(fftn(i));
   ```
2. But when I apply `fftn` on `video` I get an error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'read' for input arguments of type 'char'
>   at line
>   v=read('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\gray\myvideo.avi');

when I un-comment this line:

```
video=VideoReader('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv');
```

I get this error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'VideoReader' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I went through algorithms of `fftn` and `ifftn` but couldn't find out solution.

**Questions:**

1. How should I use `fftn` and `ifftn` to apply 3d FFT on a video sequence and get back frames from phase spectrum only?
2. Also, is there any need to convert rgb video to gray video before applying `fftn` function on video?

Comment: If this is MATLAB, please tag your question as such.

Comment: yes i am doing code in matlab. sir,will u please help me to find out solutions for above errors....?? thanks

Comment: Your error messages indicate a problem with how you load your data. Please make sure that loading your data succeeds.

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the problem is not with "fftn" but rather the "read" and "VideoReader" functions. Usually "Undefined function or method 'read' for input arguments of type 'char'" error stems from the fact that the specific function isn't in the MATLAB path or in the pwd (it's been answered before, you should be able to find more info on this).

Anyways,

> $ which -all read

and

> $ which -all VideoReader

will tell you where they are. If you see "'read'/'VideoReader' not found." then they're not there.
In that case check that they are in a sub-directory that is actually on the matlab path (>> PATH).
Make sure it's not a private dir either or they won't be accessible by the cmd line (see http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html for more info on this)

Once you get this sorted, check if it's getting loaded properly, do:

> $ video=VideoReader('C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv');
>
> $ get(video)

Cheers

Comment: thank u very much for your suggestion ..... now i have done following correction .                                                   1.instead of applying fftn directly on video ,i coverted it into frames sequences then stored it in an aaray "I" it working properly.       for t=1:T
    f1= read(video, t);                 
    f2=rgb2gray(f1);                 %convert colour frame into gray
 I(:,:,i)=f2; end                                             fftn(I);